# Using same user control with modal popup extender twice in one page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, modalpopupextender

I am having a user control inside which i am using one user control twice. User control is with modal popup extender and search panel with gridview having select button. When i click on select button, the user control should get closed. For that, i am writing foll code

```
protected void gvSearchResults_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            User usr = e.Row.DataItem as User;
            if (usr != null)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("document.getElementById('" + txtEmpId.ClientID + "').value = '" + usr.EmployeeId + "';");
                sb.Append("document.getElementById('" + txtEmpName.ClientID + "').value = '" + usr.FirstName + " " + usr.LastName + "';");
                sb.Append("$find('"+ ModalPopupExtender1.BehaviorID+"').hide();document.getElementById('" + txtEmployeeID.ClientID + "').value = '';document.getElementById('" + txtUserName.ClientID + "').value='';");

                LinkButton lnkSelect = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
                lnkSelect.OnClientClick = sb.ToString();
                lnkSelect.Text = SelectString;
                e.Row.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

In parent page, I am calling the user control like this

```
<asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label CssClass="editorLabel" ID="lblInstalledBy" runat="server" Text="Installed By:"></asp:Label>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <CustomCTRL:CTRLSelectUser Width="155" ID="SelectUserInstBy" runat="server">
                </CustomCTRL:CTRLSelectUser>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell />
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Label CssClass="editorLabel" ID="lblOwner" runat="server" Text="Owner:"></asp:Label>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <CustomCTRL:CTRLSelectUser Width="155" ID="CTRLSelectUserOwner" runat="server">
                </CustomCTRL:CTRLSelectUser>
            </asp:TableCell>
```

Now the issue is, this functionality works fine, for second usage, for the first use in parent page, the user control does not hide.

More information : the parent control is in update panel and child control too is in update panel , both having UpdateMode=conditional

Hope my question is clear! Need help! Thanks in advance..have spent couple of days for this issue but did not find anything

Comment: Have you tried `ModalPopupExtenderID.hide();`

Comment: I need to hide modalpopupextender through javascript written in code behind..so cannot do that right??

Comment: You would still need to do a postback which kinda ruins the benefit of doing it with javascript. Why do you need to hide it with JS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined to hide the modal with JS via the code behind file, you could do this:
Step 1, create a JS function in the .aspx page like this:

```
function HideModal() 
{
   $find("modalID").hide(); 
}
```

Then in your code behind, run the function on which ever event you want with this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:hideModal();", true);
```

Comment: This works for 2nd popup, 1st popup doesnt get closed ..this is my issue..as you can see I am using same user control with different id in my code